# Why a question is not shown among linked questions?

Tags: bug, linked-questions

[This comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12644/homework-questions-again#comment49504_12644) links to the question: [On the inclusion of pages-of-text-as-images in questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/on-the-inclusion-of-pages-of-text-as-images-in-questions)

However if you look at the linked questions of that question, it is not shown there: [homework questions, again](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12644/homework-questions-again)

Why did it happen here? Does it have something to do with the fact that this link was originally posted in a comment to an answer, which is now deleted? Or perhaps with the fact that I have deleted a comment containing the link, and then posted a new comment? (The old one did not contain ping.)

[image]

Comment: Related http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12026/19341 ???

Comment: The question linked in [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13030/8297) was shown only after it was added once more in a comment. (Perhaps the reason there might be migration?)

Comment: Another example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743257/whats-a-name-for-this-elementary-number-theory-lemma-where-can-i-find-it-onlin (This time the reason might be that it was migrated [from meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13330/are-there-any-other-questions-on-this-elementary-number-theory-lemma).)